# Add Up All Selected Values of ComboBox

Tags: vb.net

I have many combo boxes in which I want to add up all the selected values and display in a label. I have also created an event handler that monitors if a combo box has been selected in which will change the label constantly if a selection is detected. How do I then add up all the values based on the event handler?

```
    Dim cbCtrl = Panel1.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)()
    For Each ctrl In cbCtrl
        AddHandler ctrl.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ctrlSelectedIndexChanged
    Next

Private Sub ctrlSelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'MsgBox(CType(sender, ComboBox).Text)
    For Each ctrl In Panel1.Controls
        If (ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(ComboBox)) Then
            For i = 0 To 'LastComboBox ???
                i = i + ctrl.SelectedItem
                label.Text = i
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it you are already using a 'for-each' to get all the combo box controles, so you could;

```
Private Sub ctrlSelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  dim total as integer = 0 
  For Each ctrl In Panel1.Controls
    If (ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(ComboBox)) Then
         total += CInt(ctrl.SelectedItem)
    End If
  Next
  label.text = total.tostring
End Sub
```

But if you're working with numbers, why don't you use a nummericupdown?

Comment: Thank for this. I was overthinking or was thinking at all. However, when trying your newly edited code, I get an error when using the TryCast function. The error basically says, "integer" is of value type when it should be of reference type. The code before your edit worked fine. If you could edit it back I can mark as answer.

Comment: This is even better/shorter; For Each ctrl As ComboBox In Panel1.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)